# Structuring database using Parse

Tags: ios, database, object, parse-platform

I'm using Parse (www.parse.com) for the backend database for an iPhone app.  I'm creating a fitness application and want advice as the best way to structure the classes and relationships.

A few needs for the database:

1)`Sets`(have attribute or weight and reps)

2)`Exercise` (a single instance of an `Exercise` which can contain multiple `Sets`)

3)`Workout` (which will be a single instance for a particular workout which will represent 1 single day.  No single day can have 2 `Workout` objects.  Can contain multiple `Exercise` objects.

Then I also need some classes for `Routine` which is independent from the ones above.

4) `Routine` can contain `ExercseForRoutine` objects (which will look the same as `Exercise` but will just be used for routines, will not be able to add sets to.

5) `ExercseForRoutine` will be added to `Routine`, but not related to the actual `Exercise` objects that will be used when the user enters workout data, this object is just used to create a Routine.

Any advice on tips and how to structure this using Parse would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything and encountered a problem, or do you just want someone to do this for you?

Comment: Is this an ad for parse? If so, it's very clever. If it's a question, on the other hand, the question is not specific or problem-centered enough for SO.

Comment: It's a question, not an ad.  I need to take what I listed above, and create a database model in Parse.

Comment: I don't think people should dismiss his question. I've had a similar roadblock. I don't think the issue has to do with Parse.com specifically, but instead with schema design for non-relational database such as the one provided by Parse.com.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get too hung up on your object model or your data store. If you haven't done so already, generate a list of core [use cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) and use those to drive your object model. But assume that you will iterate on it until you find a good fit with your domain. The one thing that sounds like it might be a bit fishy about your spec is writing the single day constraint into your Workout class. That doesn't sound like it's essential to the domain and probably will be awkward to code (e.g., what happens if I start my workout at 11:55pm?).